# three LT1764A in parallel - what's wrong?

Tags: power-electronics, ldo

I've bought a lot of LT1764A LDO. 
To get more current, I've put 3 of them in parallel as in the schematic below.
According to LTspice simulations, there should be at most 1.5V voltage drop whenever the input is, say near 20V. But after trying the circuit in real life, I am faced with the following issues:

1. the voltage drop between input and output is at least 4V, no matter how I try to adjust the resistors.
   For example, at 20V input, I get 16V output max, and at 12V input, I get 8V output max. As a consequence, when 4A current flows in the circuit, the heatsink is rather warm.
2. Even more annoying, I cannot adjust the votage continuously: if I increase the resistance of R2, then the output voltage increases somewhat, then abruptly drops to the maximum possible voltage.
3. And last but not least, after the circuit has reached its maximum output voltage, I cannot decrease the voltage by decreasing the value of R2: the voltage is "clamped" to its maximum value.

I've begun to believe that I have damaged the LDO somehow.
Otherwise, what am I doing wrong ?

In the schematic below, we have

R1 = 7k (Adj-out)

R2 = 0.5k (Adj-ground)

L1 = 1m

C1 = 100u

C2 = 1m

Load = 4

Sine source = 20V DC + 1V AC 1000Hz

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Does LT1764 have constant current limitation? Otherwise, paralelling them will be difficult since they will not share current.

Comment: If you have one, use an oscilloscope to visualize the oscillations on the regulator side of your inductor. If you don't have, use a multimeter set to AC to at least measure amplitude. My guess is that you've built a rather complex oscillator that generates several tones of different frequencies; when looking at the envelope of that signal, you'd probably be able to get a higher output voltage, but since you're (rightfully) low-pass filtering the output, you're seeing far less voltage.

Comment: By the way, do the same for the output of your circuit (i.e. look at it as AC). If I'm right, it might still contain significant ripple

Comment: Regarding the last comment, yes you're right. Not tried to check at the output of the LDO yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this **will work BUT** the regulators **will NOT share the load**.
What will happen is that between 0 and 3 A output current, one regulator will take most of the load. Between 3 and 6 A output current, one regulator will take **ALL** current, the 2nd will take the rest of the current.

Why is that so ?

Because the internal reference voltages of these regulators are not **exactly the same**. This results in the regulator with the highest internal reference voltage taking all the load. Since it's internal reference voltage is higher it will want to regulate to (for example) 5.05 V while the other regulators regulate to 5.00 V and 4.95 V.

The 5.05 V regulator "wins" since it pulls up the voltage and the other regulators think: the voltage is too high, I do nothing !

Only when the 5.05 V regulator has to supply so much current that it's current limiting function cuts in will the voltage drop until it hits 5.00 V and then the 2nd regulator starts helping.

To summarize: these regulators are not suited to work in parallel like that by just connecting them parallel. You need some additional circuitry, like this:

[image]

As mentioned in the comments you might also experience oscillations and weird behavior because of using these regulators in a way for which they are not designed !

Comment: *"these regulators are not suited to work in parallel"* - although [this datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1764afb.pdf) does show two such regulators in parallel (page 20). Does that make a difference?

Comment: @RogerRowland What I meant was: "not suited to just connect in parallel" Note how in the datasheet's circuit there's an opamp and 2 series resistors at the input to make the two regulators share the same current.

Comment: FakeMoustache, I like your explanation, but can't figure out how this explains the 4V drop and the "clamping" effect.

Comment: RogerERowland, this is probably a stupid question but in their datasheet, the second LDO is not LT1764A but LT1764A-3.3, and it has not a adj pin but a FB pin. What does it mean ? also, how can I parallelized 3 LDO with this method ?

Comment: @MikeTeX Well spotted, but I don't know what that means - either it's showing *how* you can parallel fixed and adjustable LDOs or it's showing you that you can *only* parallel fixed with adjustable. In any case, I don't have the experience to suggest how you could/should use three in parallel. The datasheet says nothing about it so maybe a question for LT?

Comment: They use R1 and R2 to measure the current and an Opamp to generate a feedback signal to equalize the currents. For this reason the -ADJ variant is needed, so that it can accept the feedback signal.

Comment: Mario, can I replace the LT1764A-3.3 in the top by LT1264A with adj in some way? also, do you think there is a cheaper alternative to their LT1366 ?

Comment: Yes you can replace the top LT1764A-3.3 with a different type, just give it a **separate** voltage divider (like R6 and R7 in the schematic in my answer) to set it to the output voltage you want. It needs a separate divider as the divider of the 2nd LDO is under influence of the opamp. You cannot have that for the first LDO.

Comment: You can replace the LT1366 opamp with a different opamp but watch the **max supply voltage** and the **input common mode range**.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration can't work due to the different and variable offsets present inside the measurement circuitry (inside adj pin), which LTSpice is not modeling. Since you can't dig inside the part model, to simulate the same effect another way, run LT spice with 3 separate resistor dividers from the output to each adj pin and assign the resistors some 5% tolerance, rather than perfect nominal, values.. Then consider that each regulator is trying to modify its output pin until it's internal reference matches the adj pin exactly, and now you've got 3 LDO's fighting for control of the same node all with ever so slightly different goals for it.

Comment: ChateauDu, I have replaced R1 = 7k by three resistors between the adj-out pins of each LDO, with value 21k + 5% (21 = 7*3 so this should be equivalent). Yet, the LTspice simulation still gives 18.5V output at 20V input, more or less the same results as previously.

Comment: Sorry on mobile so can't post schematic.  But this is not what I meant.  Connect all 3 LDO outputs. Then run 3 separate 7k, one fr each adj input to the common output.  Then run one .55k, one .6k, and one .65k resistor from the adj terminals to ground.  Separate voltage dividers from the common output to each adj pin, with slightly different values.

Comment: ChateauDu, I've done that. In fact, there is no need to give 5% tolerance, and different values for the adj bottom resistors: it appears that if the adj resistors are 0.55 kOhm, then the output voltage falls to 16V, in comparison with 0.5 kOhm that gives 18.5V. So, it appears that a slight difference in the resistance causes a huge difference in the output, in contradiction to what is expected here (the ratio of R1/R2 is very small). I will try to put a 0.45kOhm resistance in my real life tries, just to see if this is exact. The pb is that there is no more ripple reduction in the simulations.